# Java: How to return values from mouseEvent/keyboardEvent methods?

Tags: java, mouseevent

I have a mouse event method that stores the amount of clicks as an integer called x. I want to use my x variable data for another class or method, but the compilation will fail if I try to return data to make it a class variable. What should I do?

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
   int x = e.getClickCount();
}
```

Comment: Make `x` (a better name) and instance field of the class; supply a `getter` to get the value from the class

Comment: You can set value for any instance variable instead of local variable like you did. Just call a setter method for instance variable which will be available even in anonymous class.

Comment: Mikita, I didn't know that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You could do following and use class_var for another class or method.

```
int class_var = 0;

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
   int x = e.getClickCount();
   class_var = x;
}
```